# Girl in a rose garden, who can pick the course of her life by touching different roses

Tags: story-identification

I have a memory of reading a short story maybe by Ann Rinaldi, Mercedes Lackey, Robin McKinley, or Marion Zimmer Bradley about a girl who goes into a rose garden and every time she touches a rose, different storylines for her life appear.

Answer (score 4):

It is the short story **"Roses by Moonlight"** from the collection [Book of Enchantments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Enchantments) by Patricia C. Wrede, published in 1996.

> A young woman named Adrian is bitter and jealous of her younger
>   sister, Sam's, success, popularity, and looks. While avoiding Sam's
>   party, **she meets a woman who takes her to a garden of roses. Each rose
>   contains a possible future for Adrian, success in work, love, failure,
>   death, or continued bitterness against her sister.** She finds one
>   flower, only a bud, that shows her and Sam agreeing to work harder to
>   get along. She is told she may pick just one flower, but she decides
>   to forego the garden, and chose her own future. The woman and her
>   garden vanish, and Adrian, still not wanting to go back to Sam's
>   party, decides that there will always be time to talk to Sam tomorrow.

[From a blogger's Review:](http://outofthelockbox.blogspot.com/2012/08/a-short-story-worth-reading-roses-by.html)

> It tells the story of a girl, Adrian, who is jealous of her younger
>   sister, Sam. From Adrian’s perspective, Sam has everything—friends,
>   looks, and success.
>
> While ignoring a party that Sam is having, Adrian meets a strange
>   woman who brings her to a garden of roses. Adrian is enthralled by the
>   beauty of the roses, and goes to pick one. The woman stops her with
>   the warning to choose one and be careful about which she chooses.
>   **Adrian quickly learns that each rose contains a potential future. She
>   travels the garden, sniffing roses, and being treated to every
>   possible future she could have from riches to dying of cancer. None of
>   the roses, though, offer what she is looking for.**
>
> Finally, she sees a rose that seems to be struggling. Unlike all of
>   the other roses in the garden, this one is disheveled and barely in
>   bloom. When Adrian sniffs it, she is treated to a scene between her
>   and Sam talking and apologizing to one another for how they treated
>   each other over the years. The woman appears at Adrian’s side and asks
>   if that is the rose Adrian wants. Adrian thanks the woman but declines
>   her offer to choose a rose. She leaves the garden understanding what
>   the future can bring and resolving to make it her own.

Comment: So, **none** of the authors listed above then :-))

Comment: @Richard Apparently. :P

Comment: A swing and a miss is perfectly acceptable in my book. At least they took a swing.

Comment: And now I also know why this author was familiar to me. I read her "Enchanted Forest Chronicles" series in my youth, during my dragons and magic phase.